# Not getting Google Ad words Link Id from Test Client Account by using Test Manager account for Link third-party app analytics to Google Ads

Tags: google-api, google-ads-api, google-api-client, google-analytics-campaign-builder

I am working with Google AdWords Manager account. I need to get all campaign deatails of client campaigns. For this process client is need to get **Link Id** from adwords panel by follow this process

Tools >> Linked accounts >> Third-party app analytics >> Details >> Create Link Id >> Fill Form with Following Details

App Analytics Provider : Other Provider

Provider Id: 4602942452

Platform: Android

Package Name: com.lionmobi.netmaster

Then Click on Create Link ID

But got following error : An error occurred. Please try again later.

View Snapshot[image]

Please help me to get Link Id of google Ad words

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming related. Stack cant help with a server issue on Google author should contact google support assuming there is a google support for this product.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am facing similar issue even sent email to adwords api support team but did not get any response.